# Stop Javascript once I identified an element with the inspector

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefox

I'm using Firefox to get information of a HTML website in order to do some automation with Python and Selenium. So far, stuff was great and worked as expected.

Now I have the following situation:

1. An element appears only when moving the mouse over an item, activated by JavaScript.
2. Once I move the mouse away, the element disappears, again by JavaScript.

How do I stop JavaScript immediately after I have identified the element?

I have tried:

- deactivating JavaScript completely. But then the element does not even appear.
- deactivating JavaScript after I used the inspector [image: icon]. However, pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> does not work, because I'm not on the debugger tab, but in the inspector tab. I can't move my mouse since the element disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use keyboard shortcuts to switch to the debugger tab. I.e.

1. Use [image: icon] to identify the element
2. Do not move the mouse once you hover over the element
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to activate the debugger tab
4. Press <kbd>F8</kbd> to pause execution
5. Use the mouse or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to go back to the inspector tab and analyze the element